# JMeter response time vs threads graph - data point

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, response-time, time-to-first-byte

What data point this graph is using? Is the graph representing TTFB (time to first byte) or TTLB (time to last byte)

[image: jmeter graph]

Here are the settings:

[image]

Comment: What is the current configuration in `Settings`? Perhaps some clue is there.

Comment: I have added an image of the settings, there nothing to suggest what data point its using

Comment: Hello, Any feedback on my answer ? If ok which I think it is you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graph is representing TTLB (time to last byte) because it uses JMeter's Response time

If you want TTFB (time to first byte), you need to use [Latency](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. Thus the time includes all the processing needed to assemble the request as well as assembling the first part of the response, which in general will be longer than one byte

If you want to display TTFB, a trick could be to replace latency with response time columns values and then display values in graph

Answer (score 2):

In JMeter :

- response time is Time To Last Byte (TTLB)
- latency is Time To First Byte (TTFB)

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html