# Understand Response Time

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, jmeter, response-time

I'm trying load testing using JMeter and application is developed using .Net
When I see JMeter Log, these are the values:
Latency: 142
Connect: 81
Elapsed: 142

When I checked IIS Log file for the same request, I noticed "Time-Taken" column is: 31
All values in milli-seconds.

Since JMeter Latency includes connect time I'm assuming processing time for that request is 142-81= 61

Why is there a discrepancy between JMeter Elapsed time and IIS Log file "Time-Taken" value?

Is there anything else considered in JMeter elapsed time calculation?

I'm executing JMeter in NON-GUI mode with no listeners.

Comment: IIS Logs have a resolution of 16ms, so you'll see numbers that are multiples are 16, 32, 48, etc. (though often will be +/- 1ms).  Also, the logs are supposed to include network time.

Answer (score 0):

The 30 missing miliseconds are mostly read time of the response that the IIS obviously is unaware of, so both calculations are correct regarding their point of view

If you download a big file the *discrepancy* probably will be higher.

See also JMeter's [TTLB Vs TTFB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175020/jmeter-response-time-vs-threads-graph-data-point/53183036?r=SearchResults#53183036)